# Need help on the Dynamic Binding During Initialization idiom

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization

I have the following code:

```
class A {
  public:
    A();
    virtual int Compute() = 0;

    int inited_val;
};

class B: A {
  public:
    B(int data): mydata(data) {};
    int Compute();
    int mydata;
};

A::A() {
  inited_val = Compute();
};

int B::Compute() {
  return mydata; // long computation...
}

int main() {
  B b(42);
  return 0;
}
```

which will not work because it's not possible to `B::Compute` in the constructor of the base class (it would call `A::Compute` which does not exist).

How can I ensure that `inited_val` is filled from the `Compute` function in the derived class? I could construct an object from `B` and fill it afterwards or using an init function that is called directly after the constructor, but that seems error-prone (I might forget to do so).
(Imagine the `Compute` function is costly and uses data only available in the derived class.)

I found proposals how to solve this problem on http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom and tried to implement the approach with a `create` function, but it's not clear to me how to write `A::create` without an explicit dependency on `B`?

```
A* A::Create() {
  A* p = ???;
  inited_val = p->Compute();
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to change inheritance as public and initialize inited_val from derived class constructor?

Comment: That would be possible, but everyone deriving from A would need to do so and not forget that. (And it would also be duplicating code because the line would be the same in all derived constructors.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<class T> class Wrapper : public T
{
public:
  template<class... Types>
  Wrapper(Types&&... Args)
    : T(std::forward<Types>(Args)...)
  {
    inited_val = Compute();
  }
};  


int main() 
{
  Wrapper<B> b(42);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Create` like this

```
template <class T>
static std::unique_ptr<typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, T>::type> Create()
{
    auto t = std::make_unique<T>();
    inited_val = t->Compute();
    return t;
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
auto b = Create<B>();
```